# Google Sheets translated dates?

Tags: date, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, google-translate

I am trying to implement a date on Google Sheets in a way that it is translated to a different language programatically:

- If I have `=TEXT("01/01/2020","DD MMMM YYYY")` I get `01 January 2020`.
- If I change my Google sheets language settings to spanish, I will get `01 Enero 2020`.

However, I am looking for some `=TRANSLATE('ES', TEXT("01/01/2020","DD MMMM YYYY"))` so even though my settings are set to English, I still get `Enero` instead of `January`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(TEXT(TODAY(), "dd mmmm yyyy"), "en", "es")
```

then:

```
=PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(TEXT(TODAY(), "dd mmmm yyyy"), "en", "es"), "de ", ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this but I don't know how accurate it is:

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(TEXT("01/01/2020","DD MMMM YYYY"), "en", "es")
```